# How to get email errors when sending emails in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I am sending emails with

```
public Response sendConfirmationEmail(String prefix, User user) {
    String emailConfirmToken = createEmailConfirmTokenIfRequired(user);
    verifyEmail
            .data("link", createEmailConfirmationUrl(prefix, user.getEmail(), emailConfirmToken))
            .data("emailConfirmToken", emailConfirmToken)
            .data("name", user.getName())
            .replyTo(replayTo)
            .to(user.getEmail())
            .subject(String.format("%s - Account Confirmation", appName)).send();
    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(user).build();
```

how to know if sendmail failed due to some reason like incorrect sendmail password or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `io.quarkus.mailer.Mailer` then `send` will thrown an exception if something goes wrong.

If you use `io.quarkus.mailer.reactive.ReactiveMailer` that returns a `Uni` which has a dedicated error handler.

**Update**

`io.quarkus.mailer.MailTemplate`'s `send` method return `Uni<Void>` which you need to subscribe to.
You current code does not do that.

Comment: How to know which one I use? `verifyEmail` is of type `MailTemplate`. If I use one with `Uni`, how to handle errors then? I have an impression they are ignored.

Comment: I subscribed in several ways, but it never triggers. Also, I don't see any signature to get error type. For example, `onFailure()` doesn't send any information to listener.

Comment: There are onSuccess and onFailure callbacks that will be called if things complete fine or with an erroe

Comment: How to know details about failure?

Comment: The exception you have in onFailure should have the details

Comment: @geoand, Do you have any ideas on how to catch errors like "email not found" with `Uni<void>`? I couldn't find a valid document to achieve this. Can you please help me sort it out? I referred to this documentation [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference).

Comment: @geoand, Do you have a idea how to do catch errors like email not found with  Uni<void> I coudn' find valid document to achiver this, Can you please help me to sort it out, I refer this doc. [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer-reference)

Comment: See https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.4.0/tutorials/handling-failures/ on handling errors